# Logic – Deductive proof with quantifiers (Fitch/LPL 13.30)

Tags: logic

Here is the question from Language, Proof and Logic (LPL). Problem 13.30:

```
1. | Likes(carl, max)
2. | ∀x [∃y (Likes(y, x) ∨ Likes(x, y)) → Likes(x, x)]
   |–––
...|
?? | ∃x Likes(x, carl)
```

I haven't had an issue with any of the other questions in this chapter, but this one is really throwing me for a loop. I suppose my issues are caused by carl and max (not nice guys, apparently). I tried finding hints and solutions on the internet, but I couldn't find a solution nor something helpful enough anywhere. According to [Trinity University](http://www.trinity.edu/cbrown/logic/chapter13problems.html), it requires not a single subproof. I tried this many ways, but always ended up at a dead-end. My most recent attempt was to add this:

```
3. | Likes(max, carl) ∨ Likes(carl, max)                    ∨ Intro, 1
4. | ∃y (Likes(y, carl) ∨ Likes(carl, y))                   ∃ Intro, 3
```

But that didn't get me anywhere… Fitch tells me that I may not use that to deduce that `Likes(carl, carl)` through `→ Elim`. I tried to introduce `∀x` first, but this did not help either. This is a very confusing problem for me.

Comment: @zagadka. In case the line "?? | Exists y(x, carl)" does not contains a typo: What is meant?

Comment: @jowehler I meant that the "??" represents whatever number that line happens to be, since I do not know that number. It is nothing important. I did miss "Likes" after the y, however. I fixed that.

Comment: Now remains my question why this line contains y and x? I suppose it should read either x or y.

Comment: @jowehler Ah! Sorry about that, it looks like there was a single lingering PEBCAK error ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your comments I assume the last line claims "Exists x Likes(x,carl)".

To prove the claim, take x = carl.

If in line 2 you take x = carl and y = max, then line 1 with Likes(x,y) implies Likes (x,x), i.e. Likes (carl, carl), q.e.d.

Do you agree?

Comment: That worked very well! And Trinity was right, no subproof needed!